# Magento backend - CMS edit page broken

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

This is what I see when I browse cms edit page in magento:

[image]

This bug is not visible in cms block edit page or category/product edit pages. Just the CMS > Page.

I tried updating to the latest version (1.9.3.8) and disabling all extensions. Non of these worked. Also, there's no javascript error on page. 
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was caused by en extension called Magento Twitter Cards
(https://github.com/laurent35240/magento-twittercards).
Disabling all extensions in local.xml file did not disable the adminhtml layout that caused this issue.

In order to solve this I commented Twitter Cards tab in file 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/twittercards.xml

Comment: You'd mentioned "I tried updating to the latest version (1.9.3.8) and disabling all extensions." This isn't a default magento extension ;-)

Comment: I tried to disable all extensions by changing local.xml file "disable_local_modules" to true. That didn't have any impact. Afterwards I tried to disable extensions one by one. That showed me the cause of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all CSS files have been updated to 1.9.3.8 in skin/adminhtml/default/default and try the site in incognito mode.

Make sure all layout and template files in app/code/design/adminhtml were replaced and cache flushed or var/cache directory deleted.

If you are using a custom adminhtml theme, disable it entirely.

Comment: I'm not using a custom theme. I re-uploaded all admin design/skin files. Problem still not fixed. The issue was there before updating magento. I tried to update in order to solve it.